# How to divide polygon into equal length but irregular widths based on depth and coastline

Tags: polygon, line, buffer, st-subdivide

I've been having issues with dividing my polygon (coastline to 300ft depth contour around Oahu) on ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0. I need to create 100 equal-length polygons along the coastline, but the other side is based on a depth contour. I've drawn examples here [image].

I got errors with Subdivid Polygons, and I tried using Buffer, as suggested by a colleague. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

(edited 2/27, clarified and updated question)

Comment: Hi, could you precise what do you mean by 'length' and 'width', maybe with a sketch of what you want to achieve on top of the current screenshot? I'm not sure to fully understand... Also, from what I understood, you may end up with invalid polygons, self-intersecting themselves in some specific cases (e.g in narrows bays). So maybe you need one more rule?

Comment: @swiss_knight I have updated the question and drawn an example of what I'm trying to do. Polygons need to be one mile long along the coastline and the other side follows the depth contour.

Comment: @BERA I have updated the question and drawn an example of what I'm trying to do. Polygons need to be one mile long along the coastline and the other side follows the depth contour.

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want:

[image]

this is how I computed 5 'same length' polygons:

- convert polygon into 2 long lines and populated numeric field by 0 and 5 (see labels)
- used topo to raster to interpolate surface inside buffered polygon
- derived contours as polygons from raster and clipped them by original polygon.

Note: you need a small cell size to keep continuous lines inside narrow polygon bits.

**UPDATE after post update**.

Create 2 lines and flip one of them so they both head in the 'same'direction:

[image]

1. Export one and split it by length, note count of resulting lines. Populate integer field by their OID.
2. Export second and split it by count. Populate integer field by their OID.

Merge both lines:

[image]

Populate FromZ field by sequential number minus 1, Populate ToZ field by sequential number:

[image]

Use above 2 fields to create 3d lines, triangulate them and use 1m contours and original polygon to create multiple polygons:

[image]

Comment: I have updated the question and drawn an example of what I'm trying to do. Polygons need to be one mile long along the coastline and the other side follows the depth contour.